# android Get file name and path from Download directory

Tags: android, download, path, directory

I'm trying to copy a file from download folder to another directory.
i used this code to get the file path

```
 int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE=1;
        Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFile.setType("*/*");
        chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
        startActivityForResult( chooseFile,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

I also used

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent returnIntent) {
    // If the selection didn't work
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        // Exit without doing anything else
        return;
    } else {
        returnUri = returnIntent.getData();
        String src = returnUri.getPath();
        Toast.makeText(this, src, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

The code works fine if the file is outside the download directory, when in it the path which i get is in the form of number not the actual name of the file like:
/document/2399
this gives an error of file not found
while the path from the root is:
/storage/emulated/0/myDB.db3
this works fine

pls help me to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code works fine if the file is outside the download directory

No, it does not. It works fine if the scheme of the `Uri` happens to be `file`. Most of the time, it will be `content`.

> I'm trying to copy a file from download folder to another directory.

Use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. This works for both `file` and `content` schemes. Then, use standard Java I/O to copy the content from the `InputStream` to your desired location.

Comment: any example how to do this ?

Comment: @NoorHossain: [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41969439/115145) has some code for this. [This](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/v1.9/Diceware/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/diceware/PassphraseRepository.java) and [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/v1.9/ContentEditor/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/contenteditor/TextRepository.java) demonstrate reading from `openInputStream()`, though not the copying part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the new code:

```
    int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE=1;
    Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    chooseFile.setType("*/*");
    chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
    startActivityForResult( chooseFile,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

And used:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent returnIntent) {
        InputStream is = null;
    // If the selection didn't work
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        // Exit without doing anything else
        return;
    } else {
        // Get the file's content URI from the incoming Intent
        Uri returnUri = returnIntent.getData();
        try {
            is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(returnUri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BackUpHelper.importDB(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

public static void importDB(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    OutputStream os = null;

    try {
    String currentDBPath =  DataBaseHelper2.DB_PATH+DataBaseHelper2.DB_NAME;
    File outPut = new File(currentDBPath);

        os = new FileOutputStream(outPut);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];



        while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {


            os.write(buffer);


        }
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.export_successful,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.export_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }finally {
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();
    }

}
```